# Why is there no DDD Slack or Discord or IRC

Tags: domain-driven-design

Why is there no online community for Domain Driven Design? There used to be a Slack channel but from what I can tell it no longer exists.  I find it hard to believe that there are too few people interested in DDD to warrant on line discussion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There used to be a slack channel but from what I can tell it no longer exists.

The [ddd-cqrs-es](https://discord.gg/sEZGSHNNbH) slack channel moved to discord.

Comment: interesting I searched for ddd in discord and got nothing.  Thank you.

Comment: haha - searching for ddd in disboard (probs not official) gets you a good laugh - https://disboard.org/servers/tag/ddd (note: slightly nsfw)